# session error windows Failed to read session

Tags: php, joomla, permissions

I reinstall apache server and and copy my Joomla project. 
I add port 8080 and 4433 in my rules in firewall incoming rules 
I run http://joomla:8080/
And I get

```
session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: c:\Apache24\sessiontmp) in C:\Apache24\Sites\Joomla_3.6.4-Stable-Full_Package-jino-ru\libraries\joomla\session\handler\native.php on line 259
Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Failed to start the session
```

I define session.save_path = "c:\Apache24\sessiontmp" in php.ini
And new directory c:\Apache24\sessiontmp becomes read-only even if I change permissions.

How can I run joomla if it worked on previous server? 
When I change dir permissions from read only to writeble it returns to read only

Comment: What version of PHP are you using ?